# I was reading a book about a boy who was able to travel through time, and i am trying to remember its name

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, time

A couple years ago, I read a book about a boy that was able to imagine a clock in his head, and make the hands of the clock spin, forward and backwards, allowing him to travel through time. I believe that the clock that he was imagining was a grandfather clock, and he had help from a another person who had the same power. Also, there was something about him coming home and finding his house burned down.

Answer (score -2):

The book "There will be Time"  by Poul Anderson seems to meet your criteria.  The boy's name is Jack.  I don't know about the clock in the head, but he does meet other people with the same ability from a variety of time periods.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_Will_Be_Time